# PHP MongoDB ordered distinct with skip and limit

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, nosql

Is there anyway to order a distinct query in MongoDB (PHP)? Would even be nicer if I could apply skip() and limit() on it. But I haven't found any ways to do this yet.

In SQL I would do something like this in the follow way:

```
SELECT distinct(fieldname) 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY fieldname
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 100
```

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2130
I don't think this will be possible..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this sort of query using the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2:

```
db.collname.aggregate(
    { $group : { _id : "$fieldname" }},
    { $sort : { _id: 1 }},
    { $skip : 100 },
    { $limit : 10 }
);
```

There are some [limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/#limitations) to be aware of, in particular:

- Results are returned in-line so cannot exceed the maximum document size (16Mb for MongoDB 2.2)
- If any single aggregation operation consumes more than 10 percent of system RAM the operation will produce an error